# My package doesn't work for R 2.15.2

Tags: r

I have a package called `rpackage` on a local (corporate) repo. When I run `install.packages("rpackage")` it tells me that:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rpackage’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

I have built this package using `R CMD INSTALL --build .` , released to the local repo and also ran `tools::write_PACKAGES()` to update the `PACKAGES` files. When I run `R --version` I get:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

And when I run `R CMD INSTALL --build --version` I get:

```
R add-on package installer: 2.15.2 (r61015)
```

The local repo directory structure follows the [official documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository) and has been working until I updated to R 2.15.2. The structure is:

```
\\server\folder\R\bin\windows\contrib\
    2.11\
    2.12\
    2.13\
    2.14\
    2.15\
\\server\folder\R\src\contrib\
```

If I run `install.packages("rpackage")` in R 2.15.1 I have no problems. Is there something special I need to do to get it to work with the new version of R?

I noticed the CRAN servers use a slightly different directory structure. For example, the CSIRO CRAN mirror uses:

```
http://cran.csiro.au/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/
```

Any idea about how to fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you set up the local repository to work with R 2.15.2 setting the appropriate option for `repos`? install.packages gets the `repos` from `getOption('repos')`

Comment: Here's what I get `getOptions('repos')` for local repo entry: `file:////server/folder/r`

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, no I don't get the error in  2.15.1

Comment: I meant is the `repos` option the same.

Comment: Sorry yes. The same for both. Both use the repo settings in `.Rprofile` as per [Hadley's README at github/devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools)

Comment: I set up a totally new repo on my local drive. Added it to `.Rprofile` and released a clean bare bones package (using `package.skeleton` plus a daft function) and have same issue. I'm filing a bug report.

Comment: The weird thing is that: `install.packages("//server/folder/r/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/rpackage.zip", repos=NULL)` works fine

Comment: @imanuelc: having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156426/did-the-subdirectory-structure-of-package-repositories-change-as-of-r-2-15-2. Did anything come back from r-devel yet (bug report)?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, neither the help files or the error message explained why this error was occurring. As it [turns out](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-November/065155.html), `install.packages()` also fails when the source package is not available, but the binary does. This is not documented behaviour (or more generously - it is not clearly documented):

> For binary installs, the function also checks for the availability of a source package on the same repository, and reports if the source package has a later version, or is available but no binary version is. This check can be suppressed by `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")`

To fix, `options(install.packages.check.source = FALSE)`. This can also be included in your `.First` function.

Comment: should the value set really be "no", or is FALSE actually OK?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if imanuelc's solution will work for everyone, as it did not work for me:

```
> options(install.packages.check.source = FALSE)
> install.packages("rstudio", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library", dep=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rstudio’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

In my case I've seen this error come and go for certain packages such as tm, rjson, etc. I know that there *is* a version of all of this packages for R 2.15 because most of them actually come with my IDE and I'm just trying to make them install into a particular directory (and I want the install.packages statement there for future coders with different IDE's).

I can't say that I know the root cause, but for me the work around is downloading the binaries directly from a mirror and installing them "manually" in the code.

Comment: You have a lot of stuff that isn't really relevant for an answer.  Also - is 'rstudio' a package you want to install or did you want to install the [RStudio IDE](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/)?

Comment: I think there *is* an `rstudio` package, but it's a weird one -- it comes with RStudio, and I don't know whether it's actually on any repositories or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading R to the new version.

To do that first update `sources.list` file. You can do this by using following command:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line to this file:

```
deb http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ wheezy-cran3/
```

Then do:

```
apt-get update
```

Remove older version:

```
apt-get remove r-base-core
```

Install using the command:

```
apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```