# Did the subdirectory structure of package repositories change as of R 2.15.2?

Tags: r, repository, cran

Kind of embarrassing / a no-go, but since it hasn't been that long that I've moved from "pure user" to "beginner-developer", I've never actually read the CHANGELOG when a new R version came out - well until today (and I have the feeling I should make this a habbit) ;-)

Yet I'm not sure if the supposed change actually occurred since I couldn't find anything about it at a first glimpse at the [CHANGELOG](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-2.15.2.html) of R R 2.15.2:

### Actual question

Is it possible that the (subdirectory) structure of package repositories changed from

`./bin/windows/contrib/2.xx/`

to

`./src/contrib/2.xx/` or even `./src/contrib`?

Or at least that the `PACKAGES` file now needs to live here: `./src/contrib/PACKAGES`?

### Background info

Up to version 2.15.1, the following path worked to install packages from my local package repository:

```
path.repos  <- "L:/R/packages"
repos       <- file.path("file://", path.repos)
```

Function `contrib.url` would take `repos` and expand it to the right subdirectory:

```
> contrib.url(repos)
[1] "file:///L:/R/packages/bin/windows/contrib/2.15"
```

But when I try to run `install.packages()`, I get the following error for R 2.15.2:

```
> install.packages("mypkg", 
+     lib=file.path(R.home(), "library"),
+     repos=repos,
+     type="win.binary"
+ )
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file = tmpf) :
  cannot open compressed file 'L:/R/packages/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>
```

When I do the same with R 2.15.1, everything works smoothly.

### Due dilligence

There are some references with respect to repositories in the [CHANGELOG](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-2.15.2.html), but the only section I found that gives me some evidence that the supposed change occurred is this:

> PACKAGE INSTALLATION
>
> > For a Windows or Mac OS X binary package install, install.packages() will check if a source package is available on the same repositories, and report if it is a later version or there is a source package but no binary package available.

Just had a look at the [official documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository) again and got the idea that maybe arg `type` is not passed along to `contrib.url()` correctly as it seems to me `install.package()` is looking at the place for `type="source"` packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132111/my-package-doesnt-work-for-r-2-15-2#comment17892021_13132111

Comment: @mnel: thanks for the pointer. Good opportunity to update my SO skills ;-) What's the recommended behavior in such a situations? I feel like I've added some more details to the question you linked to, but I see that it's not desirable to have duplicates. Should I weave my question into the other one or do I just wait until mine is closed, but still existent for anyone looking for it?

Comment: I'll flag to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular bug isn't the same as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132111/my-package-doesnt-work-for-r-2-15-2#comment17892021_13132111).

This issue relates to checks `install.packages()` now runs before installing. As Rappster said, it [tries to find a source package to compare the binary version with](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/NEWS):

> For a Windows or Mac OS X binary package install, install.packages() will check if a source package is available on the same repositories, and report if it is a later version or there is a source package but no binary package available.

So a simple way of squashing this message is creating the `R/src/contrib` directory and running `tools::write_PACKAGES()` in that directory to create (an empty) `PACKAGES` file.

And of course, the reason you aren't getting this message in 2.15.1 is that it doesn't do the checking (see R NEWS quote above) that 2.15.2 performs.

I have submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15092) of my issues. No news yet. May post it to the R mailing list as well.